# JqueryMobile checkbox doesn't like "data-inline"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a web app with MVC 3 / Razor and jquery-mobile. In jquery-mobile, normally you can add `data_inline = "true"` to an object's attributes and it will prevent the element from stretching all the way across the screen, like so:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.value, options, new { data_inline = "true" })
@Html.ActionLink("Text", "Action", null, new {data_role="button", data_inline="true"})
```

Both of those work fine. But on a checkbox...

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.value, new { data_inline = "true" })
```

... it doesn't seem to do anything, and I still get a nasty stretched checkbox. Adding `data_role="button"` doesn't help (not that I expected it to).

Is there any reason why this is so? Any good way I can get my checkbox to not be stretched without resorting to manual CSS modifications?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The jQM Checkbox does not support `data-inline`. All you need to do is change the `label` CSS property `display` to `inline-block`.

```
<label class="inline">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk0" class="ui-btn-inline" />Check me
</label>

.inline {
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```